# Program that listens to a TCP/IP port for text and execute (emulate) a key stroke on keyboard?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard, port, tcpip, emulator

I am looking for a program to be run on Windows Vista that would listens to a TCP/IP port and execute or emulate a keyboard's key stroke (or a combination of keystrokes, such as Ctrl + D). It's like [AAC Keys](http://www.aacinstitute.org/downloads/aackeys/AACKeys.html), except that AAC Keys only listens to serial port.

Thanks and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program something in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) for that. Look at the TCP function set and the Send() function. TCPListen() in particular will listen for TCP connections on a specified port and TCPAccept() will check and accept the connection to the created socket, and the Send() function emulates any keystrokes you want. You can use a conditional in a loop to check the socket for an accepted connection and perform a keystroke set of your choice once accepted.